# Скрипт. Приклеить несколько inline-blockов разных по высоте, один под другой, если они занимают 2 и более строки

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Имеется несколько одноименных inline-blockов, последовательно расположенных в родительском. Из за ограниченной ширины родителя эти блоки расположены в несколько строк, и содержат разное количество контента, который меняет их высоту, и каждая следующая строка выравнивается по самому высокому блоку из предыдущей строки. И получается, если в предыдущей строке другие блоки имеют небольшое количество контента, то между ними и следующей строкой (соответственно и блоками из следующей, строки) образуются пустое место. Как сделать, чтобы блоки из следующей строки не обращали внимание, на выравнивание строки по самому высокому блоку из предыдущей а приклеивались к блокам расположенным выше? [Вот небольшая заготовка](https://jsfiddle.net/jy5yw692/4/) для тех кто не понял о чем я))

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">Равным образом консультация с широким активом представляет собой интересный эксперимент проверки новых предложений. Таким образом начало повседневной работы по формированию позиции влечет за собой процесс внедрения и модернизации существенных финансовых и административных условий.</div>
    <div class="child">Значимость этих проблем ь в формировании системы обучения кадров, соответствует насущным потребностям.</div>
    <div class="child">Равным образом консультация с широким активом представляет собой интересный эксперимент проверки новых предложений. Таким образом нообразный и богатый опыт постоянное информационно-пропагандистское обеспечение нашей деятельности позволяет выполнять важные задания по разработке новых предложений.</div>
    <div class="child">Равным образом консультация с широким активом представляет собой интересный эксперимент проверки новых предложений. Таким образом начало повседневной работы по</div>
    <div class="child">Равным образом консультация с широким активом представляет собой интересный эксперимент проверки новых предложений. Таким образом начало повседневной работы по</div>
    <div class="child">Значимость этих проблем настолько очевидна, что консультация с широким активом способствует подготовки и реализации существенных роль в формировании дальнейших направлений развития. Повседневная практика показывает, что новая модель организационной деятельности играет важную роль в формировании системы обучения кадров, соответствует насущным потребностям.</div>
    <div class="child">Значимость этих проблем настолько очевидна, что консультация с широким активом способствует подготовки и реализации существенных финансовых и административных условий. Равным образом постоянный количественный рост и сфера нашей активности влечет за собой процесс внедрения и </div>
</div>
```

Comment: используйте http://masonry.desandro.com или http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/0rh7byb6/

Comment: то, что надо, спасибо!